# Why does StreamWriter overwrite my file?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I'm using `SteamWriter` to write something to a text file, however its overwriting the old data with the new data.
How can I make sure it will just add the new data instead of overwriting the old data?
my code:

```
class Program
{
    const string filename = @"C:\log.txt";
    static void Main()
    {
        FileStream fs;
        fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs);
        writer.WriteLine("test");

        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note, I would make use of `using` instead of that ugly closing at the end.
`using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
{ 
 using(var writer = new StreamWriter(fs)
 { 
  writer.WriteLine("test"); 
 } 
}`

Answer (score 12):

If you use `FileMode.Create`, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx):

> Specifies that the operating system should **create a new file**. If the
>   file *already exists*, **it will be overwritten**. This requires
>   FileIOPermissionAccess.Write permission. FileMode.Create is equivalent
>   to requesting that if the file does not exist, use CreateNew;
>   otherwise, use Truncate. If the file already exists but is a hidden
>   file, an UnauthorizedAccessException exception is thrown.

So you need to use `FileMode.Append` instead, if you want to add content to the end of the file:

> Opens the file *if it exists* and **seeks to the end of the file**, or
>   **creates a new file**. This requires FileIOPermissionAccess.Append
>   permission. FileMode.Append can be used only in conjunction with
>   FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek to a position before the end of the
>   file throws an IOException exception, and any attempt to read fails
>   and throws a NotSupportedException exception.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: The documentation is unclear if "it will be overwritten" means that existing bytes in the file will be preserved, just overwritten by each new write (i.e. overwriting current data from the start of the file) or if the entire file will be truncated before writing new data.

Answer (score 1):

To append to the file you can update the position of the stream to the end.

```
...
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        // To append, update the stream's position to the end of the file
        writer.WriteLine("test");
    }
}
...
```

On a side note, if you are intending to overwrite the file, and the length of the original file is longer than the length of the new data you need to use SetLength() on the underlying file stream when you have finished writing out the file. In other words,

```
    ...
    {
        writer.WriteLine("test");
        fs.SetLength(fs.Position);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: I think you mean `FileMode.OpenOrCreate`, as `FileMode.Create` will overwrite the file, and your `fs.Seek` should be done before you create a `StreamWriter` using the `FileStream`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I was following the OP's code so hadn't stopped to think about that! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string path = your file path;
   using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path,true))
           {

                    sw.WriteLine("string here");
           }
```

Comment: The flush here is unnecessary - close flushes.

Comment: Although I do have to say I disagree with your method for opening a file. I would have used a `using(StreamWriter sW = new StreamWriter("FILE", true)){`

Comment: Now that code is broken. Remove the two ifs inside the `using` and add a `)` after `true)`

Comment: @Ruirize now?  i dont have a IDE to test it :( sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out the problem, I thought I would suggest an easier solution

```
File.AppendAllText(filename, "test");
```